# strtotime was not working in php with m-d-Y format in php?

Tags: php

i have m-d-Y date format but i want Y-m-d format using strtotime, but it doesn't work?

```
$date_time = '05-23-2017 01:00';
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date_time));
```

but it will give output "**1970-01-01 01:00:00**" instead of "2017-05-23 01:00:00"

Comment: you can try it in your local system, it will not work, and it's not duplicate Question.

Comment: How is PHP supposed to guess that this is supposed to be `m-d-Y` format? You need to make that explicit. See the duplicate for how to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$date_time = '05-23-2017 01:00';

$newdatetime = str_replace('-', '/', $date_time);

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($newdatetime));

// Output: 2017-05-23 01:00:00
```

The [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) documentation reads:

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed.

Comment: Yah thanxx.. now it's work...! :)